# Eclipse/Pydev: is there a way to temporarily and quickly disable the auto closing bracket feature?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, pydev

While I like and enjoy the feature of auto-inserting closing bracket when I input opening bracket in Eclipse/Pydev most of the time, there are occasions that I want to disable it, such as adding a missing opening bracket. I was wondering if there's any way to quickly and temporarily disable the feature on-the-fly, maybe a keyboard shortcut? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such feature right now, but you can get close: you can add a keybinding to open the page where that preference is defined (preferences > pydev > editor > typing > "automatic parentheses insertion").

To add the shortcut: ctrl+shift+l (twice), search for 'typing' and add the mapping.

If that's not enough for you, please add a feature request in the PyDev features tracker (or better yet, as it's open-source, you can provide a patch to add that feature -- should be easy changing the preference even in the PyDev scripting. See: http://pydev.org/manual_articles_scripting.html )